# python asyncio aws assuming role not able to run in async

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to use python asyncio to assume a role on aws which will eventually read / write to dynamodb. However, in my many attempts, it seems like assuming role is still still reading synchronously.

**What I have done - to assume a role on aws**

```
async def aws_session(i):
    print("aws_support called for, ", i)
    sts_client = client("sts")
    response = sts_client.assume_role(RoleArn="xxx",
                                      RoleSessionName=f"xxcccx")
    return response


async def main():
    imei = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    tasks = []
    for i in imei:
        print("doing task:", i)
        task = get_event_loop().create_task(aws_session(i))
        tasks.append(task)

    for f in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
        result = await f
        print(result)



loop = get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

**issue**

The results that are returned looks to be occurring synchronously because it gets printed out to screen every 2 seconds, instead of in a non-uniformed timing.

**current result**

```
doing task: 2                # Runs immediately
doing task: 3                # Runs immediately
doing task: 4                # Runs immediately
doing task: 5                # Runs immediately
doing task: 6                # Runs immediately
aws_support called for,  2   # Waits for 2 seconds then prints out
aws_support called for,  3   # Waits for 2 seconds then prints out
aws_support called for,  4   # Waits for 2 seconds then prints out
aws_support called for,  5   # Waits for 2 seconds then prints out
aws_support called for,  6   # Waits for 2 seconds then prints out
result for, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6    # Prints out everything out instantly
```

**expected result**

```
doing task: 2
doing task: 3
doing task: 4
doing task: 5
doing task: 6
aws_support called for,  2
aws_support called for,  3
result for, 3
result for, 2
aws_support called for,  4
result for, 4
aws_support called for,  5
aws_support called for,  6
result for, 6
result for, 5
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It's hard to reason about this code because it cannot run - `process_topics` doesn't take arguments, and you're passing it one, and you're not awaiting anything in `fetch_information`, so it would exit immediately when run, along with the rest of the program. Also, `wait()` with a single awaitable doesn't make sense, you can just await it directly. Finally, and most importantly, `aws_session` doesn't await anything, so there's no hope of it being executed in parallel within asyncio. You need to use an async-aware aws API.

Comment: Hi, i've amended 3 of the 4 points you have mentioned. thanks for that. however, regarding `aws_session` where i am not awaiting for anything. how should it be done?

Comment: @user4815162342 i've simplified my code to target the problem.

Comment: You cannot use a non-async library inside asyncio, the libraries you use must be designed for async and provide awaitable entry points.

Comment: Googling aws async python reveals [this library](https://pypi.org/project/aioboto3/) - perhaps that's what you could use instead?

Answer (score 1):

there's nothing async in your `aws_session`.

It's basically blocking the loop until it's done, then the next routine runs an blocks again...

you might want to consider using `run_in_executor`:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor

Comment: hmm, i'll check out `run_in_executor` as well. but just wondering. how should `aws_session` be made to run as `async`? because its `sts_client.assume_role` that is making the actual call to `aws`

Comment: Unless you mean that this `sts_client.assume_role` cannot be made to be async in the way that I coded it to be?

Comment: It seems to me that `sts_client.assume_role` is blocking IO. 
It blocks the entire thread waiting and does not allow the asyncio loop to run other coroutines.